# Appending string to byte array for transmission over TCP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, byte

I need to append some text/string to a byte array, for transmission over TCP.

I tried:

```
byte[] msg1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\u00C3\u00C4\u00C5\u00C3\u00A2\u00A1sometext");
```

but this doesn't get me the right result when sent to TCP.

Then I tried with the following:

```
byte[] msg2 = new byte[] { 0xC3, 0xC4, 0xC5, 0xC3, 0XA2, 0xA1};
```

Now when sending msg over to TCP, it's the correct result. But how do I add `sometext` to `'msg2'`

Comment: Have a look at Memorystream and Streamwriter. Or TcpClient.GetStream

Comment: `byte[] sendmsg = msg2.Concat( anotherByteArray );` - you know how to get a byte array from a string

Answer (score 1):

I used `System.Buffer.BlockCopy`

```
byte[] rv = new byte[msg.Length + test.Length];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(msg, 0, rv, 0, msg.Length);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(test, 0, rv, msg.Length, test.Length);
```

Anyone's got a better way please add.